# How to change the font-text size based on a device using inline css?

Tags: css, wordpress, inline-styles

I have `WordPress` site where I use a plug in to create a gallery.

I created a gallery and embedded it into my site.

However, the text for the image description covers the entire image size on the mobile.

How can I use inline `CSS` or other ways to change the font-size for the caption dynamically based on the device?

I have the following inline code right now, but that keeps the size of 17px all the time.

```
<style scoped>
.on-the-fly-behavior{
font-size:17px;
}
@media (min-width:200px){
.on-the-fly-behavior{
font-size:15px;}
}
</style>
<div class="on-the-fly-behavior">My Image Caption<div>
```

I want the font-size for the caption to be 17px on `Desktop/Laptops` and 15px or less on `Mobile` devices.

Comment: You need to swap the values or use `(max-width:200px)` instead. Your media query translates to "if viewport is at least 200px wide – set font size to 15px". So you're currently setting the desktop size to 15px whereas 17px is your "mobile first" default.

Comment: I would go for a *linear equation* calculating the `font-size` relative to the current viewport `100vw` given the font size at the smallest vp (e.g. 200px) and a font size at a desktop vp (1920px). This would yield a `font-size: calc(0.117vw + 14.768px); /* (200,15)(1920,17) */`

Comment: Check my [Codepen](https://codepen.io/renevanderlende/pen/YzEaKvO?editors=1100) for some background info, 'Math in a Nutshell' section.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try the below media query instead of the current one:

```
@media all and (max-width:570px){
    .on-the-fly-behavior{
        font-size:15px;
    }
}
```

The above media query will change the font size to 15px for all devices that are lower than 570px( I have used 570px because some large screen mobiles have this size. You may use 492px if you want ) in width.

Comment: Thank you very much. That works as a charm.